# How can I use Lucene's PriorityQueue when I don't know the max size at create time?

Tags: lucene, lucene.net

I built a custom collector for Lucene.Net, but I can't figure out how to order (or page) the results.  Everytime Collect gets called, I can add the result to an internal PriorityQueue, which I understand is the correct way to do this.

I extended the PriorityQueue, but it requires a size parameter on creation.  You have to call Initialize in the constructor and pass in the max size.

However, in a collector, the searcher just calls Collect when it gets a new result, so *I don't know how many results I have when I create the PriorityQueue*.  Based on this, I can't figure out how to make the PriorityQueue work.

I realize I'm probably missing something simple here...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

PriorityQueue is not `SortedList` or `SortedDictionary`.
It is a kind of sorting implementation where it returns the top M results(your PriorityQueue's size) of N elements. You can add with `InsertWithOverflow` as many items as you want, but it will only hold only the top M elements.

Suppose your search resulted in 1000000 hits. Would you return all of the results to user? 
A better way would be to return the top 10 elements to the user(using `PriorityQueue(10)`) and
if the user requests for the next 10 result, you can make  a new search with `PriorityQueue(`**`20`**`)` and return the next **10** elements and so on.
This is the trick most search engines like google uses.

`Everytime Commit gets called, I can add the result to an internal PriorityQueue`.

I can not undestand the relationship between `Commit` and `search`, Therefore I will append a sample usage of PriorityQueue:

```
public class CustomQueue : Lucene.Net.Util.PriorityQueue<Document>
{
    public CustomQueue(int maxSize): base()
    {
        Initialize(maxSize);
    }

    public override bool LessThan(Document a, Document b)
    {
        //a.GetField("field1")
        //b.GetField("field2");
        return  //compare a & b
    }
}

public class MyCollector : Lucene.Net.Search.Collector
{
    CustomQueue _queue = null;
    IndexReader _currentReader;

    public MyCollector(int maxSize)
    {
        _queue = new CustomQueue(maxSize);
    }

    public override bool AcceptsDocsOutOfOrder()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public override void Collect(int doc)
    {
        _queue.InsertWithOverflow(_currentReader.Document(doc));
    }

    public override void SetNextReader(IndexReader reader, int docBase)
    {
        _currentReader = reader;
    }

    public override void SetScorer(Scorer scorer)
    {
    }
}
```

---

```
searcher.Search(query,new MyCollector(10)) //First page.
searcher.Search(query,new MyCollector(20)) //2nd page.
searcher.Search(query,new MyCollector(30)) //3rd page.
```

**EDIT for @nokturnal**

```
public class MyPriorityQueue<TObj, TComp> : Lucene.Net.Util.PriorityQueue<TObj>
                                where TComp : IComparable<TComp>
{
    Func<TObj, TComp> _KeySelector;

    public MyPriorityQueue(int size, Func<TObj, TComp> keySelector) : base()
    {
        _KeySelector = keySelector;
        Initialize(size);
    }

    public override bool LessThan(TObj a, TObj b)
    {
        return _KeySelector(a).CompareTo(_KeySelector(b)) < 0;
    }

    public IEnumerable<TObj> Items
    {
        get
        {
            int size = Size();
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
                yield return Pop();
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
var pq = new MyPriorityQueue<Document, string>(3, doc => doc.GetField("SomeField").StringValue);
foreach (var item in pq.Items)
{
}
```

Comment: But here's the thing -- to sort, I obviously have to complete the entire result set first, so I have everything to sort.  So, if I have a search that returns 100,000 results, and I want to give the user the first X results when sorted by, say, date, then I have to add all 100,000 results to the PriorityQueue, correct?

Comment: Also, I'm sorry -- meant "Collect," not "Commit."  I have edited the question.

Comment: `have to complete the entire result set first` + `I have to add all 100,000 results to the PriorityQueue` Yes, but there will be *at most M elements* in the queue at any time during collect process.

Comment: Okay, I think I see my disconnect -- when I say Max Size is X, that doesn't mean I can't keep adding and adding all day long, it just means that it will "throw away" anything that doesn't "fit" based on the sort.  I was thinking I added them all, THEN the queue did a big batch sort.  You seem to be saying that the sort is incremental, so every time I add something, it's eval'd at that time.  True?

Comment: Yes you are very correct, therefore its fast. It doesn't do a `batch` sort on all results.

Comment: Awesome answer and explanation... one question though (probably a moronic one) but how do I iterate over the queue after it is populated?

Comment: ... I exposed the CustomQueue (via a getter) and am looping with:         while(collector.Queue.Size() > 0) {
            Document doc = collector.Queue.Pop(); } ... just feels wrong and/or dirty to me for some reason... What do you guys think...

Comment: @nokturnal you can add an `Items` method to `CustomQueue` as  **`public IEnumerable<T> Items()
{
    int size = Size();
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        yield return Pop();
    }
}`** which would allow you to use *`foreach`*

Answer (score 0):

The reason Lucene's Priority Queue is size limited is because it uses a fixed size implementation that is very fast.

Think about what is the reasonable maximum number of results to get back at a time and use that number, the "waste" for when the results are few is not that bad for the benefit it gains.

On the other hand, if you have such a huge number of results that you cannot hold them, then how are you going to be serving/displaying them? Keep in mind that this is for "top" hits so as you iterate through the results you will be hitting less and less relevant ones anyway.