# Lucene.Net: How to grab the next 10 results after a document that has a certain field value?

Tags: lucene, lucene.net

Suppose I have a query in Lucene.Net 3.0.3 that matches 1,000,000 documents, and each document has a field named ProductID with a unique value. How can I grab the next 10 items immediately after a specific ProductID?

For instance, grab me the next 10 items after ProductID 4264423.
The ProductID could be anywhere within the 1,000,000 matches, and sorted however I wish.

One brute force solution is to loop through all the ScoreDocs, and use the FieldCache to find the correct ProductID, then grab the next 10. However, that seems inefficient, since we'd need to populate a huge ScoreDocs array.

Another idea is to use a custom Collector, along with FieldCache to look for the correct ProductID, but as far as I know, Collector's aren't sorted.

Perhaps a solution is to use a combination of a custom Collector with a PriorityQueue, use the FieldCache to find the correct ProductID, note the Score of that document, then grab the next 10 items based on Score. (Although, if there are similar Score values, how is that handled?)

Please provide code samples, as I'm a Lucene.Net newbie. (Sample code preferably in C#.)
If a custom Collector + PriorityQueue is a viable option, here is some sample code to assist: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7938433/1145177